# Problema con bucle while en C

Tags: c, bucles, while

Tengo este código en C, es para validar letras, creo que todo está bien, pero no sale del while interior del subproceso y no se por qué.
Por otro lado definí las funciones `get_aux_buffer` y `substr`, pero no se si están bien definidas.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define MAX_STRLEN 256
#define MAX_BUFFERS 10

char *get_aux_buffer(double t);
void validar(char pal[50]);
char *substr(const char *s, int desde, int cuantos);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char palabra[20];
    printf("Ingresa la palabra para comprobar si es un palindromo");
    scanf("%s",palabra);
    validar(palabra);
    return 0;
}

void validar(char pal[50])
{
    int i,j,band;
    char num[10];
    strcat(num,"1234567890");
    i=1;
    band=0;
    while (band==0 || i<=strlen(pal))
    {
        j=1;
        printf("bucle1\n");
        while((j<=strlen(num))||(band==0))
        {

            printf("bucle2\n");
            if (substr(pal,i,i)==substr(num,j,j))
            {
                band=1;
            }
            j=j+1;
            printf("%d", j);
        }
        i=i+1;
    }

    if (band==1 || strlen(pal)<3)
    {
        printf("Ingresa solo una palabra, minimo 3 caracteres");
    }

}

char *get_aux_buffer(double t)
{
    static char buffers[MAX_BUFFERS][MAX_STRLEN];
    static int count = -1;
    count = count+1;
    if(count==MAX_BUFFERS)
        count = 0;
    return buffers[count];
}


char *substr(const char *s, int desde, int cuantos)
{
    double t;
    char *buf = get_aux_buffer(t);
    strncpy(buf,s+desde,cuantos);
    buf[cuantos] = '\0';
    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Sale del `wihle` interior del subproceso y no se por qué.

No, NUNCA sale del `while` interior.

---

La condición de **continuidad** del bucle interior es:

```
while((j<=strlen(num))||(band==0))
```

La variable `j` debe ser menor que `strlen(num)` o `band` debe ser `0`; mientras que `j` aumenta en cada vuelta, `band` siempre se mantiene en valor `0`, por lo que después de 10 vueltas del bucle, la condición es:

```
while(false||true)
```

Que siempre será verdadero (falso o verdadero es: verdadero), por lo que **SIEMPRE** seguirá en el bucle, hasta que el programa finalice por hacer algún disparate con la memoria… cosa que seguramente pasa en la función `substr` que sin pararme a analizarla ya tiene el problema de estar usando Formaciones de Tamaño Variable (examina [estos hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vla+%5Bc%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D) para averiguar por qué eso es un problema).

---

Tu algoritmo para comprobar si una palabra es palíndroma es innecesariamente complejo, sólo debes comprobar que la letra *n* y la letra *longitud - n* son la misma:

```
int es_palindromo(char *palabra, unsigned longitud)
{
    for (unsigned indice = 0, final = longitud / 2; indice < final; ++indice)
        if (palabra[indice] != palabra[(longitud - 1) - indice])
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wxbgIipQatwYtKkN).